# Position of Sigma indices

Tags: amsmath

I use `\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{|K_i|} I_{j}}{\sum_{j=1}^{|K_i|} C_{j}}` to show a sigma expression but as you can see in the figure, the indices are not on top and below the symbol. Any way to fix that?

[image]

P.S: I am using `amsmath` package.

Comment: This is normal. The fractions become super tall if they are typeset in display mode. You can use `\frac{\displaystyle .... }{\displaystyle ....}` to force larger versions.

Comment: This is the generally accepted (by publishers) presentation in fractions or in-line in text.  If the indices are set above and below, as they would be in a one-level display, they would increase the height unreasonably, without making them any easier to understand.  Thus it is the default.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it isn't really clear from the OPs question whether this is text style math or displayed math.

Comment: @daleif: Right. With `\displaystyle` I was able to see them on top and bottom. Thanks.

Comment: As barbara say. don't. If you want nonetheless, use `\sum\limits`, as `\displaystyle\sum` would make very big summation symbols, completely out of place in the context.

Comment: @daleif-- It doesn't matter.  A careful publisher will change it in the editorial pass.